# SharePoint InfoPath data connection credentials

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, infopath

A previous developer has already created a InfoPath Form which connects to a data source and is published in a SharePoint form library. I'm trying to make a new connection but I don't know which username / password has been used, as a result no data can be retrieved with my connection.

Is there a way to explore InfoPath and find at least a username?

```
<udc:SSO AppId="SSSIP" CredentialType="NTLM" />
```

And I have added my windows account to SSSIP

Thanks

Comment: if there is a data connection file (.udcx file) associated with the Infopath form you may find that out with looking in there.

Comment: The InfoPath Form connection is made using UDC. I checked UDC and it has NTLM ?
I have access to the server where the published web service resides but not sure if I can check there

Comment: That means the credentials are stored in the Secure Store Service Target App ID of "SSSIP", check the secure store service account. Then you can use something like this to retrieve the credentials: https://sharepointobservations.wordpress.com/2015/02/05/retrievingrecovering-secure-store-credentials/

Answer (score 1):

Create copy of xsn file, change extension to cab and open it as zipped file. In form folder will be manitest.xsf file, open it in notepad and there should be all data connection strings and settings, here you should find what you need.

If not, in cab folder will be more files, try search in xsd files.

Comment: In the UDC file I can see use of SSS
 <udc:SSO AppId="SSSIP" CredentialType="NTLM" />

Answer (score 0):

The events log of the server where the web service was published gave me the user account when an existing successful connection was made.